# Apple Pencil SDK - sensitivity and distinguishing touch input

Tags: ios9.1

Does the Apple Pencil SDK provide sensitivity information and does it distinguish touch input from stylus vs finger (or other capacitive sources)?

Answer (score 1):

There is no Apple Pencil SDK as such.

Apple just added support for more attributes to the pre-existing UITouch class. As of iOS 9 each touch event now has `type` (which includes "UITouchTypeStylus") and `force` properties, and as of iOS 9.1 also has properties for altitude and azimuth.

You can see more [here in the UITouch documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/), in [sample code from Apple here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/TouchCanvas/Introduction/Intro.html) and in a [tutorial by Caroline Begbie on Ray Wenderlich's site here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/121834/apple-pencil-tutorial).